# Pattern of source-tracking two-element radio interferometer

Tags: astronomy, interferometry, radio

In a two-element adding Interferometer, the phase difference comes about as EM-waves from a source at an angle $\theta$ to the baseline-normal generally cover different path lengths when travelling to the antennas. This then leads to a periodic interference pattern, where the current phase in the pattern is decided by the relationship between the current path difference and the wavelength of incoming radiation.

I believe I understand how this makes sense for interferometers operated in transit mode, i.e. the antenna is pointed at some fixed point in the sky while the object (let's assume a point source) traces out its orbit. Drawing a triangle between the tips of the antennas and the point source, I get slightly different lengths for the two "long-sides" of said triangle at each point in time, i.e. the path difference is ever-changing, and a periodic pattern occurs.

However, I'm having trouble to understand how this pattern can occur when operating the interferometer in "tracking mode", i.e. the baseline normal is always pointed right at the point source (or at least the angle between point source and baseline normal is always held constant). In this case, shouldn't the path lengths to each of the antennas be constant as well, therefore not prompting a change in path difference and no periodic pattern?

I believe that what I am getting at (constant angle vs. varying angle $\theta$), is actually the reason that for the tracking interferometer, the maximum amplitude stays constant, whereas it varies for transit operation. But where then, does the periodic pattern come from? Am I wrong about this being caused by the path difference between the antennas?

Note I'm specifically asking about a point source, since interference will of course happen when dealing with different "point sources" that make up an extended source. When dealing with one single source, however, the radiation picked up at the antennas should be coherent. First pic shows tracking operation, second pic shows transit operation (point source in a) ).

[image: Interferometer operated in "tracking mode". How does this periodic pattern come about?]

[image: Transit mode interferometer. point source a), extended source b)]

Comment: Do you have an example of an interferometer that operates in what you call "tracking mode"?